# How do I query with date("l") in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to query with date name, from taxonomy `jadwal`:

```
get name day like WEDNESDAY from $day
```

My WP_Query code is:

```
$day = date("l");

$args = array('post_type' => 'post',
              'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
              'posts_per_page' => 1,
              'jadwal'     => $day,
              'meta_query' => array(array()));
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
#extract data
endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
```

My taxonomy code

```
add_action('init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_jadwal');
function cptui_register_my_taxes_jadwal() {
register_taxonomy( 'jadwal',array (
  0 => 'post',
),
array( 'hierarchical' => false,'label' => 'Pilih Jadwal','show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,'show_admin_column' => false,'labels' => array ('search_items' => 'Pilih Jadwal','popular_items' => 'Popular Jadwal','all_items' => 'All Jadwal','parent_item' => 'Parent Jadwal','parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Jadwal:','edit_item' => 'Edit Jadwal','update_item' => 'Update Jadwal','add_new_item' => 'Add New Jadwal','new_item_name' => 'New Jadwal Name','separate_items_with_commas' => '','add_or_remove_items' => '','choose_from_most_used' => '',)) ); 
}
```

Comment: You have included your code and told us what you want to happen, but you haven't told us what problem you are having. Please update your answer with details of the problem so we know what you need help with!

Comment: oh sorry this query cant cath or showing the item ,that the problem
when i use it i was make 3 post and taxonomy value same as day
but still not show the post